# How to set a URL connection as POST

Tags: java, android

I'm looking at the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

I'm not seeing an option to flag a request as a POST method.  I'd expect to see `.setRequestMethod("POST");` or something.  Am I looking at the wrong documentation?

I'm using Android 4.2 and Java 1.6.  Though I'm unsure if `javase/1.4.2` is what I should be looking for.

```
URL url = new URL(this.getUrl());
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
connection.setUseCaches (false);
```

Comment: now do `connection.getOutpuStream()` and write to it (then remember to `close()`), and the POST will be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [HTTPURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead of [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

HTTPURLConnection has [setRequestMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29)

Example:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Note: It is always better to use latest javadoc instead of old version, 1.4 is considerably older version of java.

Credit goes to [Luigi R. Viggiano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258289/luigi-r-viggiano):

My answer above just deals with how you can access `setRequestMethod`. If you don't want to use setRequestMethod, but achieve POST, as Luigi suggested, you can ignore calling 
`setRequestMethod` and just set `setDoOutput(true)`. Read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) for more information.

Comment: `new URL("http://something").openConnection()` returns an `HTTPURLConnection`: `URLConnection` is abstract. So there would be no difference from what Webnet is already doing.

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano: Reference type is URLConnection, URLConnection doesn't have any method setRequestMethod..., so reference type need to be changed to HTTPURLConnection, that is what I meant.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the actual answer needs type casting... `HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`

Comment: @Webnet, try without casting to (HttpURLConnection) and without calling setRequestMethod(). If you are writing to the outputstream after setDoOutput(), the post will be issued anyway. Check my link below.

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano: Happy new year to you too. Good luck.

Comment: If I don't case the object, my IDE doesn't recognize the return of `openConnection` as an `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, you have already more options tha the one I post

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

HttpUriRequest request = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
```